# find with exec : how to perform multistep conditional action on each file

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have bunch of php files in directory structure say /mylibs
I want to run a simple `php -l $file` on each php file which checks for syntax errors

```
find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php" -exec php -l {} &>/dev/null \;
```

thats step one, the &>/dev/null eats verbose output from php (found syntax errors or not)

The `php -l` returns 0 if no error  is found depending upon which, I want to copy them to some other dir say `/mybin`. To check if this works as expected I tried

```
find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php" -ok php -l {} &>/dev/null ; echo $? \;
```

but this simply prints 1 on the terminal and does not ask for confirmation (-ok acts same as -exec after interactive confirmation)

What am I doing wrong here ? is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`;` is the ***shell's*** command separator. Everything after it will be a separate command and won't be passed to `find`, since command parsing is done before execution. Likewise, `&>/dev/null` applies to the *entire* `find` command, *not* just to `php`, regardless of where it is located (before, in the middle, or after).

To use such operators in your `-exec` or `-ok`, you will have to explicitly call a shell:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'php -l "{}" >&/dev/null; echo $?' \;
```

Note that the special characters are inside quotes, which means they will be passed literally to `find` and then to `bash`.

This is less simple but might be more reliable with "weird" filenames:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'php -l "$1" >&/dev/null; echo $?' -- {} \;
```

---

This will display the results in a more readable form: (this is entirely about bash scripting now, not about `find` anymore)

```
find ... -exec bash -c '
    if php -l "$1" >&/dev/null; then
        echo "$1: pass"
    else
        echo "$1: fail"
    fi' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save your found files to an array, and run your php -l on each item in a for or while loop, with an if [ "$?" != "0" ] as a step.

```
find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php" -exec php -l {} &>/dev/null \;
```

I would change to

```
MYFILES=$(find /mylibs -type f -iname "*.php")
SAVEIFS=$IFS

IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for FILE in ${MYFILES}
do
  php -l ${FILE} 2&>1 >>/dev/null
  if [ "$?" != "0" ]
    then
      echo "ERROR on ${FILE}
  else
      /bin/cp ${FILE} ${NEWPATH}
  fi
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```