# How do I read every file and print out the file name before reading it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried

```
$ find Music -exec cp -v {} \>/dev/null \;
```

Got error

```
'Music/AlbumArtSmall.jpg' -> '>/dev/null'
cp: cannot create regular file '>/dev/null': No such file or directory
```

I tried

```
$ find Music -exec echo {} && echo cp {} \>/dev/null \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

And

```
$ find Music -exec echo {} \\; echo cp {} \>/dev/null \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

And

```
$ find Music -exec echo {} \&\& cp {} \>/dev/null \;
Music && cp Music >/dev/null
...
```

I tried

```
$ find Music -exec bash -c 'echo "{}" && echo cp \"{}\" /dev/null' \;
Music/4-Mat - Intro Music.mp3
cp "Music/4-Mat - Intro Music.mp3" /dev/null
```

Which looks like it would work, but it gave

```
$ find Music -exec bash -c 'echo "{}" && cp \"{}\" /dev/null' \;
Music/4-Mat - Intro Music.mp3
cp: target '/dev/null' is not a directory
```

When I took the 2nd 'echo' out.

Here is a similar, but not same, question: [find with exec : how to perform multistep conditional action on each file](https://superuser.com/questions/341601/find-with-exec-how-to-perform-multistep-conditional-action-on-each-file)

Comment: This is Linux, to copy a file to /dev/null use `cat`: `cat {} >/dev/null`. You can also use `dd`: `dd if={} of=/dev/null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have gone all round the houses without getting the right combination:

```
find Music -exec cp -v {} /dev/null \;
```

You need at least two parameters for `cp`, the source(s) and one target, which can be a file or directory. When you escape `>` you are removing its redirection properties, so `>/dev/null` then becomes a target, looking for a subdirectory in the current directory.

Note that you cannot specify individual redirections with the `-exec` option: the parameters are passed directly to the scheduled program without further shell interpretation.

For myself, I generally prefer this construct to `-exec`:

```
find Music | while read -r l; do cp -v "$l" /dev/null; done
```

I can then use all the normal shell commands in the `while` clause, including multiple commands, redirections, etc.

Note that certain characters in file names (eg embedded new-lines or leading and trailing blanks) will prevent this solution from working, while the original `-exec` answer should work for all file names. I don't have any such file names, hence my preference.

Comment: Might be enough, not quite robust though: (1) `find … | while read …` will fail if there's a newline in a filename (`-exec` is better); (2) if there's an empty named pipe somewhere, `cp` will stall until the pipe is written to (`find -type f …` would help). I still think this is a good answer (+1 btw), however it's good to know possible pitfalls. This comment is to point (some of) them.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Files with embedded new-lines will cause all sorts of problems, and I can't imagine anyone who would ever use such names, other than accidentally created, and it is unlikely in the extreme that music tracks would include such. My preferred method also fails with leading and trailing blanks, but this is worked round with `while read -r; do cp -v "$REPLY" /dev/null; done` - I use this when creating scripts, but not in ad hoc commands. I didn't want to make the answer too complicated by considering such marginal cases.